# Fierz tranformations

Tags: quantum-field-theory, parity

Consider the following quadri-linear $$ e(1234)= [\bar{\psi}_1 \sigma_{\mu \nu} \psi_2][\bar{\psi}_3 \sigma^{\mu \nu} \gamma_5 \psi_4]$$ 
Where $\psi$'s are spinors.
I came across the identity: $e(1234)=e(3412)$. I am able to prove it using the relation $ \sigma^{\mu \nu}\gamma_5=-\frac{i}{2} \epsilon^{\mu \nu \alpha \beta}\sigma_{\alpha \beta}$. But I am not able to understand it conceptually. Can somebody give a physics argument or refer to some process where I can understand this identity?

Other argument I read for this identity is

> Opposite-parity partner of $\sigma^{\mu \nu}$ is itself only, resulting in this obvious identity}

I don't understand what does this mean. Please explain.

Reference: An introductory course of particle physics by Palash B. Pal (pg 423)